# Linux commands not working in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script called AddUsers.sh. The script should take a line like this:

```
john.mccarthy@caltech.edu;1927/09/04;sudo,visitor;/visitorData
```

and return variables like this:

```
name=john
surname=mccarthy
bdate=1927/09/04    
uname=mccjoh
pass=1927
groups(array)=sudo, visitor
folder=/visitorData
```

When I run the script and give it the required text file, it is tellilng me that 'groupadd' 'chgrp' 'chmod' and 'chage' are all errors. Is anyone able to tell me why / give me any feedback?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#!/bin/bash

#check for file
while [ ! -f  $file ]
do

    #ask user for filename
    echo What is the filename?

    #reading input as file name
    read file

    if [ ! -f $file ]
        then
            echo "File not found!"
        else
            echo "File found!"
    fi
done

#process each line and make a user from the data
cat "$file" | while read line

do
    name=`echo $line | sed 's/^\(.*\)\..*\@.*$/\1/g'`
    surname=`echo $line | sed 's/^.*\.\(.*\)\@.*$/\1/g'`
    bdate=`echo $line | sed 's/^.*;\(.*\);.*;.*$/\1/g'`


    #set groups to tokenize
    groups=`echo $line`

    folder=`echo $line`

    temp2=`echo $name | sed 's/^\(...\).*$/\1/g'`
    temp1=`echo $surname | sed 's/^\(...\).*$/\1/g'`

    user="${temp1}${temp2}"

    #pass must be first 4 numbers of birthdate
    pass= ${bdate:0:4}




    #tokenise group + add to array
    declare -a groupArray

    IFS=" "
    groupArray=(`echo $groups | tr "," " "`)

    #create groups if not existing.
    for i in ${groupArray[@]}
        do
            if [ getent group $i ]
                then
                    echo "group exists"
                else
                    groupadd $i
            fi
        done

    #Create shared folders if not existing.
    if [ ! -d $folder ]; 
        then
            mkdir -p $folder
    fi

    #Create groups for shared folders
    gname=`echo "${folder:1}"`
    groupadd $gname

    #Set group as owner of directory and change permissions
    chgrp -R $gname $folder
    chmod -R 770 $folder

    #create user and add to groups
    if [ grep "^${user}:" /etc/passwd ]
        then
            echo "user exists already!"

        else
            #Create user
            useradd -m -d /home/$user -p $pass $user

            #Add user to groups
            for i in ${groupArray[@]}
                do
                    usermod -a -G $i $user
                done

            #Add user to shared group
            usermod -a -G $gname $user
    fi

    #force password change
    chage -d 0 $user

done
```

Comment: Run your script through http://shellcheck.net

Comment: Also instead of posting the entire script, it would be helpful to narrow it down to where the errors occur. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: step through it by adding `set +x` at points where you would like the script to spit out its state and `set -x` where you would like it to stop.  Typically if you wan't to monitor the whole script just place `set +x` at the top of the file, after the `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Do you have to use bash? This may be much easier in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

you could use commands in scripts with full path address. and you can extract their full path address by "which" command.
for example instead of using "chmod" you could use "/bin/chmod"
type this to find full path:
$which chmod